# Как сделать исполняемый файл из JavaFX проекта?

Tags: java, javafx, jar

Я создал JavaFX проект, теперь хочу сделать исполняемый файл из него. До я этого когда я работал с swing, я довольно простым способом создал jar файл, который запускается в два клика. Попробовал сделать также и с этим проектом, не вышло. Как это можно сделать в случае с JavaFX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл видео на youtube https://youtu.be/F8ahBtXkQzU Здесь показано, как сделать jar файл в проекте javafx, также не забудьте при создании jar поставить галочку в "include in project biold".

Answer (score 0):

Launch4j  - софтина для преобразований .jar в .exe

- указать имя файла с расширением .ехе - пример meapp.exe
  ; расш. файла обязательно.
- указать путь к .jar файлу
- header вибрать gui (графическое) / console
- вкладка jre указать min jre version - пример 1.4.0
  НО

- нужно почитать про classpath
- cmd →java -version
- можно и без .ехе, а обойтись jar-ником
- не факт что если ваша машина запускает то будет на другой